# ElasticSearch net client doen't have Fuzziness?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-client

Im having trouble with adding Fuzziness to my Match query, see the below code:

```
 var client = new ElasticsearchClient(new Uri("http://elasticsearch:9200"));

            var response = await client.SearchAsync<ExceptionLog>(s => s
               .Index("exceptions")
               .From(0)
               .Size(1000)
               .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                       .Must(m => m
                       .Match(ma => ma
                            .Field("message")
                            .Query(message)
                            .Operator(Operator.Or)
                            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.) //i want here AUTO fuzziness but it only has Equals and ReferenceEquals.
                            .ZeroTermsQuery(ZeroTermsQuery.All)
                       )
                    )
               )
                    )
               .Sort(sort => sort
                   .Field("createDate", new FieldSort { Order = SortOrder.Desc })
               )
               );
```

Below is the normal query that works fine, but how to get it in my .net code:

```
 {
        "match": {
            "message": {
                    "query": "",
                    "operator": "or",
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    "zero_terms_query": "all"
                }
            }
        },
```

Im using ElasticSearch net 8.9.3 : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

I already tried without fuzziness (maybe its by default Auto) but that doesn't work.

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!